# Windows service 64bit and 32bit

Tags: windows-services, 32bit-64bit, system.data.sqlite

I have developed a windows servce which runs perfectly on Windows server 2008 (64bit), windows 7 (64bit). I have compiled the same service in to 32 bit, but it only runs on 32bit windows 7, on 32 bit windows xp it stops unexpectedly. Service works with SQLite database ( create, insert and .. ) and Timer threads. Plse help if anyone know the issue

Comment: Do you have a log? Or an error message ?

Comment: I haven't log anything, Actully I don't know where would the error occur because it works perfectly on 64bit

Comment: Anything in the [Event logs](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DiagnoseProblems)?